# Временые переменые в цикле php

Tags: php

Вопрос на грани фола: как в php объявить переменную которая должна жить до конца цикла?
Можно в начале цикла всегда присваивать false или удалять переменную в конце цикла.
Но по мне оба варианта не интересно и не очень-то уследишь за нацатью с гаком вспомогательными переменными.
Кроме варианта внутреннюю логику цикла вынести в отдельную функцию есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде как нет.
хотя есть еще вариант, можно объединить все нужные переменные в массив? структуру массива задать до цикла, в нутри цикла эту структуру присваивать временному массиву...

```
$arrTpl = array('var1'=>'val1', 'var2'=>'');

for (.....) {
    $tmpArr = $arrTpl;
    $tmpArr['val1'] = 'newval1';
    $tmpArr['val2'] = 'newval2';
    // чота делаем
    unset($tmpArr); // необязательно

}
```

Comment: можно задавать структуру массива конечно в теле цикла, чтобы не хранить ее в памяти, но по мне так лучше отдельно, чтобы не искать потом где) это лично мое ИМХО ;)

Comment: Плюс за мыслю. Но тут возникает проблема из-за плохого стиля программирования: когда по ходу написания кода, появляется куча побочных переменных, или в цикле несколько веток if или case, каждая из которых имеет свои переменные. Так как в конце цикла они не удалялись, местами пострадала логика. Не говоря уже о том что в x-debugere такая помойка, что глаза болят.

Comment: ну тут уж -- либо пытаться избавиться от кучи переменных (или ее каклибо сократить) либо мучаться

тут решение правильное тяжело предложить. возможно можно поискать другое решение задачи.

а так, по крайней мере в массиве они будут в одном месте :)

Comment: Или найти предыдущего прогера и оторвать руки :)  
Кстати, "моё ИМХО" это тавтология, т.к. [ИМХО][1] по определению "моё".


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%85%D0%BE

Comment: про прогера -- да.  
зыж моё-мое мнение